# Android, handle inserting null using String.format()

Tags: android, sqlite

How to insert null in SQLite using `String.format()` like this?

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblCustomers (idCustomer , customerName  )" +
            " VALUES (%d , '%s')";
db.execSQL(String.format(Locale.US,
                sql,
                1, "Ali"));
db.execSQL(String.format(Locale.US,
                sql,
                1, null));// this time it inserts 'null' value as string in database, not (NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

`null` is getting converted into "null" because of `String.format()`. So you need to only insert the `idCustomer` field for new row and left `customerName`  field.

---

For that you need to insert only id field.

```
String id_sql = "INSERT INTO tblCustomers (idCustomer)" +
            " VALUES (%d)";

db.execSQL(String.format(Locale.US,
                id_sql,
                1));
```

---

Rather than using your current way, you need use [`ContentValues`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html). It will handle your null value also, as you want. So your query would be

```
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put(COLUMN_ID, valueOfID);
  values.put(COLUMN_NAME, valueOfName);
  values.put(COLUMN_OTHER, valueOfOther);
  // Insert query will be
  long insertId = database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null,
      values);
```

Comment: So what about the first query? where I inserted "Ali"? you men I have to have some `String.format()`?? and check for their nulls???? I don't think it is the best solution.

Comment: Yes you need to check for null before inserting to DB. And if name id empty/ null then I do not think there would be any good reason to insert id only to DB.

Comment: I have 25 fields to insert, you mean I check 25 fields, can you imagine how much conditions can happen?? No, I don't agree with you.

Comment: Yes you are correct. But what I say, the way you are using you have to do checks. But there is another way to handle this case. See my update..

Comment: Example at http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/android.content.ContentValues

Comment: Thanks but I knew this solution, it has performance issue, while you want insert 30K records it's not a good solution and it's better to use `db.beginTransaction()` with raw `SQLite` query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117050/discussion-between-pankaj-kumar-and-alirezaxx).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used a simple way that works like a charm!

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblCustomers (idCustomer , customerName  )" +
        " VALUES (%d , %s)";
db.execSQL(Locale.US,
                sql , 
                item.getID(), item.getNameForQuery());
```

My CustomerObject.java:

```
    public String getCustomerNameForQuery() {
         return customerName == null ? null : "'"+name+"'";
    }
```

and as you can see, I moved the single quote from the query string to my object.